# Python - Sum result to do graph

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I woul'd like extract result of differents calculs to do one graphic.

I have a lot of dataframe construct like this :

```
effectifs = data["subject1"].value_counts()
modalites = effectifs.index
tab100 = pd.DataFrame(modalites, columns = ["subject1"])
tab100["Effectif"] = effectifs.values
tab100["Fréquence %"] = round((tab100["Effectif"] / len(data) )*100, 2) 
tab100


out[]

    Subject1    Effectif    Fréquence %
0   Subject1    257         19.25
```

idem for tab101 :

```
    effectifs = data["subject2"].value_counts()
modalites = effectifs.index
tab101 = pd.DataFrame(modalites, columns = ["subject2"])
tab101["Effectif"] = effectifs.values
tab101["Fréquence %"] = round((tab100["Effectif"] / len(data) )*100, 2) 
tab101

out[]

    Subject2    Effectif    Fréquence %
0   Subject2    440         32.96
```

I woul'd like join the results of "Effectif" to make a barpolt with this differents items.

I tried to make a new dataframe with this values but I don't succeed.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please post a minimal working example of the code you're running to make the plot?